# Vert.x Postgres SqlClient closing

Tags: postgresql, vert.x

The documentation states:

You need to release the client when you don’t need it anymore:

```
client.close();
```

Is it enough to close it in `stop` of my Verticle or? Or does it mean *when you don't need it anymore in your current request processing flow*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to close it in the `stop` method. It really means when you don't have any more requests to make.